# How do I get version number from a static library?

Tags: objective-c, ios, static-libraries

I have a .a file for a library I'm linking to an iOS application. How do I know the version number of the library? I don't need to do this programmatically, I just need to get it manually once.

Comment: Manually?  Hard code it in, there should be a plist that came with the lib's source.

Comment: I want to get the version, not set it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no common theme on how to encode a version number into a static library.

Sometimes there is none present at all. 
Sometimes that is done using a header that belongs to that library. 
Sometimes it is done using a function that returns such information.
In some cases that static library is part of a pseudo framework which contains a plist that **might** contain a correct version number.

Remember, a static library by itself is not much more than a bunch of object files put into a file archive. There is hardly any additional information, not to speak of metadata.