# Get Version number from static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, static-libraries

I'm developing a **static library** and I want to return to the user the version number of the library, when they ask for it. 
I did some research and I found this link -
[How do I get version number from a static library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13279334/how-do-i-get-version-number-from-a-static-library)

Is there a solution ? 
maybe something in the .plist ? 
I can do it using a function that returns such information like version number but I don't want to put static value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static libraries don't have `.plist` files (only bundles have `Info.plist` files), so you need to return the version number via a variable or function; for example:

version.h:

```
extern unsigned myApiVersionMajor, myApiVersionMinor;
extern NSString *myApiVersion();
```

version.m:

```
unsigned myApiVersionMajor = 1, myApiVersionMinor = 9;
NSString *myApiVersion()
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"v%u.%u", myApiVersionMajor, myApiVersionMinor];
}
```